# How to show content of a a specific URL in Smarty template?

Tags: smarty

Following is my code snippet from smarty template :

```
<div id="entrancelist">
      <h2 class="heading">My Packages</h2>
      {if $user_study_test_packages.test}
        <ul class="entrancelist">     
         {foreach from=$user_study_test_packages.test item="user_test_packages" key=key}
          <li>
          <h4>{$user_test_packages.pack_name|capitalize:true}</h4>
           {if $user_test_packages.pack_expiry_date1 >= $current_date }
            <div class="fr"><span class="expiry">Expiry : {$user_test_packages.pack_expiry_date}</span></div>
           {else}
             <div class="fr"><span class="expiry_dt">This package is expired on {$user_test_packages.pack_expiry_date}.</span></div>
           {/if}
           <p class="descp">{$user_test_packages.test_pack_desc}</p>
          <div class="srtest"><a href="my_tests_listing.php?pack_id={$user_test_packages.pack_id}" class="starttst">&nbsp;</a></div>
          </li> 
         {/foreach}     
       </ol>
      {else}  
          You haven't bought any online test packages
       {/if}
    </div>
```

Now what I want to do is reaplace the text "You haven't bought any online test packages" with the content of different URL say www.google.com But I'm not understanding how should I achieve this. Can anyone help me out in this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep PHP separate from the template?

Maybe do this in your php code,

```
<?php
$gcontent = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');

$smarty->assign('gcontent',$gcontent);
?>
```

Then you can use `{$gcontent}` in your template.

You can even use query string parameters with the URL if you wanted to. More info on the php function.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp

Comment: That would always retrieve the URL even if the condition is not met (slowing down the script), or you'd have to duplicate the condition checking in PHP if it's not already there.

Comment: That is true but I would assume that the condition checking is done in PHP. Whole purpose of templating is keeping the php separate. :) At least I try to keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works for me in Smarty 3, but some might not consider it very elegant:

```
...
{else}
    {file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/')}
{/if}
```